# How to interpret geological data for Africa

Tags: geospatial, data.gov

I am currently working on a project where I need a geological map of Africa for groundwater potential. I have downloaded the [Surficial geology of Africa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15839/how-to-interpret-geological-data-for-africa) from the U.S. Department of Interior ([map URL](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/surficial-geology-of-africa-geo7-2ag)). I need assistance on how to interpret the data.

Comment: Perhaps you could give us the URL of the map you've downloaded?

Comment: This is the URL: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/surficial-geology-of-africa-geo7-2ag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer.

I downloaded the "geo7_2ag.zip", unzipped it, ran `ogrinfo -al` on the `geo7_2ag.shp` file and learned the following:

- The shapefile contains 11,977 polygons, each tagged with a GLG value.
- There are 44 different GLG values. Some of these are: DS, H2O, Mi, O, S_d
- Most of these values are explained in geo7_2ag.shp.xml and appear to represent geological eras. For example, "DS" means "Devonian-Silurian", "H2O" means "Water (River or Lake)", "Mi" means "Mesozoic Igneous", and so on.
- The data is imperfect. The "Cm" and "O" values in the shapefile are not in the XML file. The "JI" and "KI" values are spelled with a capital "eye" in one of the files and a lower case "ell" in the other.
- The geo7_2ag.e00 contains 4 layers of data:

  - an "ARC" layer with 25,285 line strings
  - a "CNT" layer with 11,978 points
  - a "LAB" layer with 11,977 points
  - a "PAL" layer with 11,977 polygons

According to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54730/e00-file-structure these data layers are intended primarily to transfer data between formats and are probably not important for you, the end user.

As a general note, gis.stackexchange.com might be able to help more with further questions, and you might look into qgis, a free tool to help interpret and manipulate geographical data.

Comment: This actually seems like a pretty good answer. They asked for help interpreting the data, and that's what you did here.